# PageFactory.initElements() doesn't always guarantee the objects are initialized- assertion fails - running on real iPhones

Tags: java, iphone, design-patterns, automation, appium

I am tying to run `appium` tests on 2 real `iPhones` using the pages design pattern.
The objects on each page are initialized using annotations like this:

```
@iOSFindBy(name = "Custom menu.")

protected MobileElement customMenuBtn;
```

and when a new page is created I use : `PageFactory.initElements` to initialize it.

When a new page is created an assertion is made to verify I am on the right page:

```
public void assertInPage() {
try {
         waitForElement(customMenuBtn);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Waiting for this element of a page that exists and isn't `null` sometimes fails and I get `NoSuchElementException`
This error is inconsistent and it can happen the first time I create this page or after I return to it.
I can't try it on simulators so I am running on real devices. 
Is it possible initElements() doesn't actually initialize all the elements even though they are all visible on screen.
I am using `appium` 1.3.4 and 1.3.5 and it happens in both.

Have been stuck on this for a few days now , any ideas ...?